# Generator object has no attribute items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, generator

While converting a generator to Pandas data frame.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(
    open('/kaggle/input/spanish-football-la-liga-champions/La Liga Champions.csv'),)
# skip the header row
next(reader)
# remove leading and trailing whitespace from all values
reader = (
    dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in reader)

df = pd.DataFrame(reader.items(), columns=reader.keys())
```

This error shows up.

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: can u confirm that ```reader``` is a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvs.DictReader` isn't a dictionary. I believe you can just directly call `pd.DataFrame(reader)` (it was changed to directly return rows as dictionaries in Python 3.8).

Answer (score 0):

After

```
reader = (
dict((k, v.strip()) for k, v in row.items() if v) for row in reader)
```

`reader` is a generator of dictionaries. As you can feed a dataframe with an iterable of dicts, you can just do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(reader)
```